# Visual Studio 2019 (Community): cannot create a new project with any specifications of programming language and operating system

Tags: visual-studio

I installed visual studio last night and no matter what I do, I am unable to create a new project with any specified language or operating system. Whenever I try, I get a message "No exact matches found".

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot]

I can only create a new solution with the default settings (Create an empty solution containing no projects). In that, I cannot add anything meaningful (only things like text files, webpages and xml files can be added to that sort of project).

I would like to be able to program in C++ (for both console and windows applications) and VB.

How do I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit 1:

After suggestion in the comments, I am now *trying* to install the additional required components (starting with universal windows development kit). The problem I keep running into is that my installation drive is D: while my workspace is on C: (horrible choice, I know). Now the installer is not letting me install the component because I don't have enough space on C: drive.

Should I just uninstall everything and start afresh, everything in D: or can I still be redeemed?

Comment: "Not finding what you're looking for?  Install more tools and features"

Comment: @John **which** tools and features, exactly?

Comment: The C++ workload, step 4.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=vs-2019

Comment: @HansPassant Question updated. Please check. Thanks.